# Upgrading SQL Server from 11 to 12

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I'm having an issue.

I'm trying to import a .bak file but having no luck since the server version I'm running is 11, and the backup was exported from a server running 12.

My question is, how do I upgrade the server from 11 to 12 so I can restore the backup?

I running the server on my local machine.

Thank you

Comment: You purchase version 12 and install it in the upgrade mode?

Comment: Which version of MSQL do you use? Standard purchased or Express? If Purchased, you need to purchase 12. If Express you can easily download and install MSSQL 12. Also you can generate scripts instead of creating .bak file. Then you can run these scripts as basic query on 11.